# Чи можна перекладати "tag" в контексті класифікації як "позначка", а не "мітка"?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-english

*Позначки* мені милозвучніше, тому неодноразово прагнув у себе на сайті зробити таку заміну.

Чи є доречною така заміна і чи не викривляє значення (використовувати прагну в такому ж значенні, як тут *Теги* — *Tags*)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Словотвір](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/teh#translation-388) дає переклад слова "tag" саме як мітки.

Чи є доречною заміна “мітки” на “позначки” - це питання досі гостро стоїть у словотворі й чіткої відповіді тут немає. Особисто я вважаю, що позначка може бути у полях типу checkbox. Мітка ж саме слугує для позначення матеріалу, відмічення його для майбутнього упізнавання. На мою думку позначка такої функції не виконує.

Answer (score 1):

Це синонiми, замiна доречна.

> ПОЗНАЧКА (спеціальний знак, зроблений для відрізнення чогось, вказівки
>   на щось),
>   МIТКА;КАРБ (такий знак, зроблений чимсь гострим); 
>   ПОМІ́ТКА (перев. письмова)

[https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/позначення](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)