# Українські відповідники hashtag, metatag

Tags: переклад, from-english

[Тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/693/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-tag-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97-%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) вже маємо думки про переклад слова **tag** - позначка, мітка.

Запрошую дати відповідь, як скласти відповідники **hashtag**, **metatag**, враховуючи деякі особливості:

1. **хешем** називають символ решітки, але смисл лексеми **хештег** - "ключове слово"
2. в українській мові є префікс **мета-**, тому виникає сумнів, чи перекладати його, чи ні.

Comment: Один раяв _hashtag_ як [_зрубка_](//drive.google.com/file/d/1mJcpvbLuVsjiEpvySqnKbKv0flhOoDvL).

Answer (score 2):

На сайты "Словотвір" до слова ***"хештег"*** найбільше голосів набрав відповідник ***"кришмітка"***, де наведене досить грунтовне пояснення утворення даного слова.

> З огляду на технічну складову питання додам коротке обґрунтування
>   назви "кришмітка". Слово hash-tag отримало таку назву не просто із-за
>   символа “решітка”, причиною використання цього символа є скорочення
>   написання слова hash-tag, коріння якого по своїй суті заходить глибоко
>   в науку про компьютери. Розробники використовють слово hash як
>   скорочення слова dictionary (словничок) що є спеціальною структурою
>   даних котра пришвидшує пошук. Hash-tag або “#tag” з технічної точки
>   зору означає те що слово “tag” проіндексується (потрапить у індекс або
>   іншими словами словничок) і надалі буде доступне для швидкого пошуку.
>   Тепер про саме слово hash, у тій же компьютерній науці існує багато
>   стуктур даних здатних виконувати роль словничка. [...]
>
> [... ]Hash-функція отримала таку назву із-за дій що вона виконує над
>   вхідними данними всередині себе. Фактично вона “кришить”, “рубає”,
>   “перемішує”, “заплутує” вхідні данні, що відповідає англійському
>   перекладу слова hash. Тобто логічним було б перекласти слово хеш у
>   цьому контексті як “криш” або "міш". Переклад слова “tag” вже
>   здійснений, і це “мітка”, поєднавши ці варіанти отримаємо “кришмітка”
>   що в одночас володіє певною милозвучністю.

Що ж до [metatag](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/meta-teg) однозначного лідера серед відповідників, поки що немає

> вказняки, надмітка, помітка, спеціальна мітка

На мою думку, можна використати слово **"метамітка"**. Ви вже вказали в питанні в українській мові є префікс ***[мета-](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=155175&page=1605)***, то чому б його не використати для утворення нового слова.